# Unpacking UPX OSX files

Tags: unpacking, upx

I was wondering if someone could provide me an UPX unpacker, which works with unix excutable files.

I've tried a bunch of already, but all of those expect .EXE's which obviously won't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: `upx -d` does not work?

Comment: I eventually figured that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the binary has been modified to prevent it, UPX itself should be able to unpack it:

`upx -d packed.bin`